# Segmentation fault in std::string::assign(std::string const&)

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault, assign

i have the indicated problem with the following code and i have no idea what it might be causing it. I searched before posting the problem, and i learned that it might be something going out of the scope like a reference to a freed memory location but i could not find it on my own.
Thank you for helping me.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class USR{
private:
    string name;
public:
    void setName(string name){  
        this->name = name;
    }
    string getName(){
        return name;
    }

};

class A{
private:
    USR* * a;
public:
    A(int size){
        a = new USR*[size];
    }   
    USR* getUser(){
        return a[0];
    }
};

int main(){
    A test = A(5);
    USR* u = test.getUser(); 
    (*u).setName("test");
    USR* u2 = test.getUser(); 
    cout << (*u2).getName() << endl;
    cout << (*u).getName() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you every one, i accepted Björn's answer because he was the first one to reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method `getUser` returns an uninitialized pointer (the constructor of `A` creates an array of uninitialized pointers). The error you see is the result of dereferencing the uninitialized pointer that method returned.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you allocated the array of pointers, but you never allocated anything for the pointers themselves.

This gives you the array of pointers:

```
a = new USR*[size];
```

But you never allocated anything for each of the pointers.

Therefore, it's crashing here:

```
(*u).setName("test");
```

because `*u` is not initialized.

---

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Allocate (and initialize) something for each `USR` pointer.
2. Don't use the double pointers. Just use a simple array of `USR` objects.

I'd prefer the latter since what you have is probably more complicated than it needs to be.

Something like this will probably do what you want:

```
class A{
private:
    USR *a;
public:
    A(int size){
        a = new USR[size];
    }   
    USR* getUser(){
        return &a[0];
    }
};
```

Don't forget that you'll want a destructor as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are only creating a new `USR*` array instead of an array of `USR` objects. Accessing the pointer in

```
USR* u = test.getUser();
```

will give you an unitialized pointer. Calling

```
(*u).setName("test");
```

will therefore segfault.

Answer (score 1):

You initialized an array of `USR*`s, but you haven't initialized the single `USR*` objects.

Answer (score 0):

As you have declared a 2D array of USR, so i think you have requirement of Array of Array of user names, although it looks weird to me why can't you simply use USR *userArray;

Anyway if you want the array of array of user names to work then you need to modify your class A as below:

```
class A{
private:
    USR* * a;
public:
    A(int size){
        a = new USR*[size];
        int iter = 0;
        for(; iter < size; iter++)
        {
           a[iter] = new USR[size_of_user_names_for_each_user_array];
        }
    }   
    USR* getUser(){
        return a[0];
    }
};
```